# What is the way to increase the drop down folder list when bookmarking in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

When you click on the 'star' you have the possibility to click on the drop down labelled 'Folder:' and make a choice among 5 folders + Bookmark bar + Other Bookmark. Why did they limit to 5 ? It is not effective. How can I increase the list of 5 folders ? Have a look to the screenshot attached.[image: 5 folders displayed]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's not about programming.

Comment: Alternatively you can probably use this chrome extension [Fast Bookmark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fast-bookmark/bkolccbclokgkhcciikgbkcmnagimjib)

Answer (score 7):

Yes this is very annoying

I have requested for an increase in the number of items of the dropdown
but still no reply from chrome developers...

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/33LM0lBJXgw

And this thread (newest)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/windows7/Stable/mQmvA-vKRxI

Also add a plus icon next to the word folder to instantly show the bookmark folder structure rather than need to click edit, browser the folder in another popup

Something similiar to firefox bookmarking system...

I really hate chrome's inefficient bookmarking method

Comment: @AkinHwan
if you find one that please reply here

Comment: @tyler.durden:The second link does return the "Chrome help page".